# ASP.NET MVC 3 HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorize-attribute

I have two controllers, AdminController and AccountController with the following code

AccountController:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _authenticationService.SetPrincipal(model.UserName);
            var exists = _authenticationService.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
            if(exists){
                 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");

            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("LogOn");
    }
```

AdminController:

```
[Authenticate]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

`AuthenticateAttribute` is inherited from `AuthorizeAttribute` and has the following code:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authenticated = false;
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //some actions
        }
        else
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        }

        return authenticated;
    }
```

`_authenticationService` is the instance of `AuthenticationService` class and `SetPrincipal()` method has the following code:

```
public void SetPrincipal(string userName)
    {
        var identity = new GenericIdentity(userName);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                principal.Identity.Name,
                DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                false,
                String.Empty,
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

            string encryptedCookie = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            var authenticationCookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (authenticationCookie != null)
            {
                authenticationCookie.Value = encryptedCookie;
                authenticationCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
            }
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
    }
```

When I debug and watch `AuthenticationService.SetPrincipal()  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true. But after redirect to Index action of AdminController in `AuthenticateAttribute.AuthorizeAttribute() HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always false. As result I redirected to LogOn view again.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think it solves your issue, but why are you using `HttpContext.Current` while you receive the current HTTP context as an argument in `AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)`.

Comment: In httpContext parameter IsAuthenticated property is false too, unfortunatelly. I can't understand what magic is happening

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere where you actually send the cookie back to the client.  In order to be authenticated on each subsequent request, you have to send the encrypted cookie back to the client so that it can pass it back to your site.

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedCookie);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

I see where you try and get the current authentication cookie here:

```
var authenticationCookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
```

But again, this is a GET, not a SET (or sending the cookie back) function line.  At this point in your authentication, if you set a debugger, `authenticationCookie` is always going to be NULL.

Also, I don't see where you validate the password in any of your actions or functions.  Ensure you are not overlooking that step.

One more thought/question/issue with your code.  You are setting a variable called `userExists` in your controller action, but the function you call is a `void` type, so...you don't need to set that variable, just call the function.

```
_authenticationService.SetPrincipal(model.UserName);
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
```

Comment: I've edited my question. _authenticationService.ValidateCredentials(string userName, string password) used for password validation. And after that I use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false) to set cookie.

Comment: @Tommy `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie();` sets the cookie and sends it back to the client.

Comment: It seems to me that after redirection to Index action of AdminController HttpContext is instantiated again. I thought it should not happen.

Comment: @anykey3 - the HTTP context only last for as long as the connection does.  Meaning for each request, a new HTTP context is created.  So anything your store there is only good for the lifetime of a single request.

Comment: @Tommy - So, maybe I should not check HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated property? But instead I should check httpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] if that is NULL or not? It seems to be not secure and not beautiful approach.

Comment: @anykey3  No, your check is fine.  Since the encrypted cookie is sent with each request, .NET will see that cookie, decrypt it and let you know if the user is authenticated.  I feel you have done a lot of modification to your project, maybe you should start a new project from scratch and gradually add your requirements back in.